# How to disable popup menu when switching tab list (Ctrl+Tab) in Kate?

Tags: linux, text-editors, kate

How to disable popup menu when switching tab list (Ctrl+Tab) in Kate?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is inherent in switching tabs, you do Ctrl+Tab and it brings you up a list to choose from.

You can always use Alt+Right & Alt+Left to cycle through each tab.

If you really want to disable the switching tab list, then:

1. `Settings`->`Configure Keyboard Shortcuts`
2. Search for `tabswitcher`->`Last Used Views`
3. Choose `Custom` & ensure `None` is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed the hotkeys from `Last Used Views` and set `Ctrl+Tab` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` to `Kate` → `Next Tab` and `Previous Tab`. But the only problem that remains is that when you press `Ctrl+Tab` on the last open tab, it does not jump to the first initial tab (you cannot press only `Ctrl+Tab` to switch to all tabs in a circle), you have to press `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` to return to previous tabs.

Comment: Yup, it is a pain that it is not circular. You could always raise a bug/enhancement request for it.